# Open Sans overwriting Lato ~ Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, css, fonts

This question has not been answered anywhere else.  There is another post like this but it's not the same issue.

I have created a theme of my own, using Blank as the fallback. I have set Lato to be my default font.

I have set Lato in the CSS, on increasingly specific elements, with `!important`.

I have carefully gone through EVERY file in the site using DreamWeaver's excellent (and it's only useful) file search funtion, searching for occurences of both Open Sans and Open+Sans in the site files, and have found nothing outside of the dev/test folders that would affect my site.

I have refreshed the cache, and I have manually emptied the pub/*/frontend files.

And yet still, the fonts are clearly Open Sans and not Lato.

If I inspect the CSS file using Firebug, I have discovered this rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url("http://www.XXX.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/XXX/ohc-dac/en_GB/fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("http://www.XXX.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/XXX/ohc-dac/en_GB/fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff2") format("woff2"), url("http://www.XXX.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/XXX/ohc-dac/en_GB/fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.woff") format("woff"), url("http://www.XXX.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/XXX/ohc-dac/en_GB/fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.ttf") format("truetype"), url("http://www.XXX.co.uk/pub/static/frontend/XXX/ohc-dac/en_GB/fonts/opensans/light/opensans-300.svg#Lato") format("svg");
}
```

Which appears to show that the font in use is indeed *called* Lato, but it is using Opan Sans *as* Lato!?  But how is this possible?  I have completely emptied the pub/static/frontend folder a number of times, where is this cached font coming from?

It's driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to supply the source files for the font that you wish to use because "Lato" is not a standard font.

Magento's LESS mixin for defining `@font-face` directives is this:

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name,
    @font-path,
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal
) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: @family-name;
        src: url('@{font-path}.eot');
        src: url('@{font-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('@{font-path}.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{font-path}.woff') format('woff'),
        url('@{font-path}.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('@{font-path}.svg#@{family-name}') format('svg');
        font-weight: @font-weight;
        font-style: @font-style;
    }
}
```

found in `/lib/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less`

As you can see, you need to have all these formats `.eot`, `.svg`, `.tff`, `.woff`, and `.woff2` in order to use this mixin. You would then place these files in `/lib/fonts/yourfont/fontfile.tff` for example.

Now to specify this as the default font, make the file `/app/design/frontend/Your/theme/web/css/source/_extend.less` with this contents:

```
@import 'lib/_typography.less';

@my-font-name: "FontName";
@font-family-name__base: @my-font-name;

.lib-font-face(
  @family-name: @my-font-name,
  @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/yourfont/fontfile',
  @font-weight: 300,
  @font-style: normal
);

.lib-font-face(
  @family-name: @my-font-name,
  @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/yourfont/fontfile',
  @font-weight: 400,
  @font-style: normal
);

.lib-font-face(
  @family-name: @my-font-name,
  @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/yourfont/fontfile',
  @font-weight: 600,
  @font-style: normal
);

.lib-font-face(
  @family-name: @my-font-name,
  @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/yourfont/fontfile',
  @font-weight: 700,
  @font-style: normal
);
```

Ideally you would have different subsets for each font-weight, but for this example I just used the same set for all. (see `lib/web/fonts/opensans` for example)

Now to re-compile the LESS you need to run `rm -rf pub/static/* var/view_preprocessed/*` from magento directory, flush cache, and flush your browser cache.

Comment: I will give this a go - thank you for the detailed explanation!  Incidentally, Lato is called from Google fonts in the header.xml file of my theme.

Comment: Your answer was almost entirely correct - I followed it to the letter but still had the issue.  So I instead uploaded the Lato font family to my theme /web/ folder.  Then changed the path in your code above to `@font-path: '../fonts/lato/Lato-Thin',` ... which finally fixed it.  Couldn't have done it without your guidance though, so thank you.